# Blueprint mandatory dependancy to mandatory dependency

Tags: osgi, blueprint-osgi

Please help me with one problem. I have an osgi bundle. Blueprint config looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0">

    <bean class="test.SomeBean">
        <argument>
            <reference-list availability="mandatory" member-type="service-object" interface="test.Service1"/>
        </argument>
    </bean>

    <service interface="test.Service1">
        <bean class="test.Service1Impl">
            <argument>
                <reference-list availability="mandatory" member-type="service-object" interface="test.Service2"/>
            </argument>
        </bean>
    </service>

    <service interface="test.Service2">
        <bean class="test.Service2Impl"/>
    </service>

</blueprint>
```

After deploy I get a java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException. If I move Service2 declaration to another bundle or change availability to optional all work fine. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you depend on a service that you also offer. BLueprint can not do this for mandatory services.

The reason is that whenever blueprint hits a mandatory reference it makes sure to resolve the dependency before commencing. Only when all mandatory references are resolved the services of the context will be published.

Comment: Is there any possibility to resolve this? I need to have a mandatory availability. If I change "availability" to "optional" then Service2 implementations appears from time to time. I need to know that at least one implementation of Service2 is binded and only after that app become initialized. Sorry for my english) I hope you'll understand what I want to say)

Comment: As far as I know in blueprint there no easy way. You might want to take a look at declarative services which supports this behaviour.

Comment: Do you know why Blueprint container works so unstable? I mean I can't be sure that all implementations of my service will be accessible. For example I have 3 services which provide Service2 interface. All services declared in one config. I can't forecast each time which services will be binded to reference-list or no one. depends-on does not help.

Comment: It is not unstable. It is dynamic. In OSGi you have to cope with the fact that service can come and go at any time (e.g because the bundle providing them is stopped). What do you want to achieve? You only want to run your code when all services are running?

Comment: Yes but dynamic I need too

Comment: This will not work. If you do not know how many services will be present. How will you determine when to start?